# foreach and intersection

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, intersections

what's wrong with my code? The usage of the foreach loop instead of the direct draw commands leads to an error that the path is not known. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance!

> ! Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named `links
>   1'.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw [name path=links 1] (0,0) -- +(10:5cm);
    \draw [name path=links 2] (0,0) -- +(20:5cm);
    \draw [name path=links 3] (0,0) -- +(30:5cm);
    \draw [name path=rechts 1] (5,0) -- +(150:5cm);
    \draw [name path=rechts 2] (5,0) -- +(160:5cm);
    \draw [name path=rechts 3] (5,0) -- +(170:5cm);

% why can't I use the foreach-loops instead?

%   \foreach \angle/\num in {10/1,20/2,30/3}{%
%       \draw [name path=links \num] (0,0) -- +(\angle:5cm);
%   }
%
%   \foreach \angle/\num in {150/1,160/2,170/3}{%
%       \draw [name path=rechts \num] (5,0) -- +(\angle:5cm);
%   }

    \fill [name intersections={of=links 1 and rechts 1, name=a}] 
        (a-1) circle (2pt) node {};

    \fill [name intersections={of=links 1 and rechts 2, name=b}] 
        (b-1) circle (2pt) node {};

    \fill [name intersections={of=links 2 and rechts 2, name=c}] 
        (c-1) circle (2pt) node {};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code works without error for me with MikTeX

Comment: Well, yes, it should, but if you remove the comment signs and put them instead to the drawing commands below, then I get the error message. Sorry for that misunderstanding.

Comment: Replace `name path` by `name path global` in the foreach loops.

Comment: I had uncommented the lines and it worked

Comment: It also works on my updated TeXLive2018 distribution, regardless of whether I compile `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`. And I do not need `name path global` to make it work. It also works if I use a loop to draw the bullets at the  intersections: `\foreach \X/\Y in {1/1,1/2,2/2}  
  {
  \fill [name intersections={of={links \X} and {rechts \Y}, name=i-\X-\Y}] 
        (i-\X-\Y-1) circle (2pt) node {};
  }`.

Comment: name path global solved the problem! Thanks to @esdd